# Azure AD B2C Graph API retrieve if user has MFA

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'd like to use the Azure Graph API to retrieve for a given user if that user has MFA setup. I can't find this information in the API docs, but it would seem like something you want to retrieve.

Would anyone of you know if this is possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with [MS Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph),

To Get information of users registered with MFA and hasn't, we can use ***isMfaRegistered*** property in [credentialUserRegistrationDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-list-credentialuserregistrationdetails?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) .

> `credentialUserRegistrationDetails` help us to get the details of the
> usage of self-service password reset and multi-factor authentication
> (MFA) for all registered users. Details include user information,
> status of registration, and the authentication method used.
> This is possible programmatically with MS Graph where you will get a JSON reports an can be plugged into other reports or can be represented programmatically itself

**Example:**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails
```

**sample output:**

```
{
            "id": "****************************",
            "userPrincipalName": "NKS@nishantsingh.live",
            "userDisplayName": "Nishant Singh",
            "isRegistered": false,
            "isEnabled": true,
            "isCapable": false,
            "isMfaRegistered": true,
            "authMethods": [
                "mobilePhone"
            ]
        }
```

**Sample code written  in C#,**

```
 GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

 var credentialUserRegistrationDetails = await 
     graphClient.Reports.CredentialUserRegistrationDetails
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```