# Azure AD Batch service API to find if the user has MFA enabled

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

When I try to authenticate an AAD user to Azure Batch account using [`AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.ipublicclientapplication.acquiretokenbyusernamepassword?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-identity-client-ipublicclientapplication-acquiretokenbyusernamepassword(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string))-system-string-system-string)), if the user has MFA enabled it is taking some time (around 30-40 secs) to receive the `MsalUiRequiredException` [AADSTS50076](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/836429/aadsts50076-due-to-a-configuration-change-made-by.html) and this keeps the user waiting unfortunately with a 'not so helpful' prompt with 'Switch To' and 'Retry' options.

I want to know beforehand that the user needs to go through MFA, so that I can redirect him to the interactive flow ([`AcquireTokenInteractive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication.acquiretokeninteractive?view=azure-dotnet)) instead.

Is there a way to know if the user has MFA flag enabled? (I could find one for [MS Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64753245/azure-ad-b2c-graph-api-retrieve-if-user-has-mfa) but not for my requirement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ***note*** that, you cannot get user's **`MFA status`** using Azure Batch Service API. You can find operations **supported** by Azure Batch Service API in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/#rest-apis).

To know user's **`MFA status`** via APIs, you can ***only*** use **Microsoft Graph API.**

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and got results like below:***

I ran the below query to know specific user's **`MFA status`** by filtering it with UPN:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails?$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'User_UPN'
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Code sample in c#:**

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var credentialUserRegistrationDetails = await graphClient.Reports.CredentialUserRegistrationDetails
.Request()
.Filter("userPrincipalName eq 'User_UPN'")
.GetAsync();
```

If you want to get **all the users** whose MFA is ***enabled***, you can make use of below query:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails?$filter=isMfaRegistered eq true
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Code sample in c#:**

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var credentialUserRegistrationDetails = await graphClient.Reports.CredentialUserRegistrationDetails
.Request()
.Filter("isMfaRegistered eq true")
.GetAsync();
```